# スクロールビュー間で画像を移動する方法

Tags: swift, ios, swiftui

swiftuiを使ってiOS用のアプリを作成しているのですが、不明な点がありましたら教えてください。あるスクロールビューに表示されている画像をドラッグして別のスクロールビューに移動したいのですが、現在の問題は、画像をドラッグして移動すると、画像がスクロールビューの外に出ると表示されず、移動できないことです。別のスクロールビューに移動してください。この問題の解決方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pageOffsets: [CGSize] = Array(repeating: .zero, count: 50)
    @State private var pageGridColumns: [Int] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 50)
    let grids = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(80)), count: 4)
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ScrollView() {
                LazyHStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: grids) {
                        ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) { num in
                            Page(str: String(num))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .frame(height: 60)
                                .offset(pageOffsets[num - 1])
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            pageOffsets[num - 1] = value.translation
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            let columnIndex = Int(round(value.translation.width / 80))
                                            let newOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(columnIndex) * 80, height: 0)
                                            withAnimation {
                                                pageOffsets[num - 1] = newOffset
                                                pageGridColumns[num - 1] = columnIndex
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                                .onAppear {
                                    pageGridColumns[num - 1] = (num - 1) % 4
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ScrollView() {
                LazyHStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: grids) {
                        ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) { num in
                            Page(str: String(num))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .frame(height: 60)
                                .offset(pageOffsets[num - 1])
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            pageOffsets[num - 1] = value.translation
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            let columnIndex = Int(round(value.translation.width / 80))
                                            let newOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(columnIndex) * 80, height: 0)
                                            withAnimation {
                                                pageOffsets[num - 1] = newOffset
                                                pageGridColumns[num - 1] = columnIndex
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                                .onAppear {
                                    pageGridColumns[num - 1] = (num - 1) % 4
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Page: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.green, .blue, .pink, .orange, .purple]
    let str: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            colors.randomElement()
            Text(str)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUIのdraggable, dropDestinationを使うとgestureを気にせずに実装することができます。

https://zenn.dev/zunda_pixel/articles/7dd3a47b0a3998

YouTubeに1つのScrollViewですが同じような要件のものがあります。これを参考にすればいけると思います。

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFiOCcm6zTo

長いですが、一応動くコードも置いておきます。

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreTransferable

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var topPageItems: [PageItem] = (0..<20).map { i in
      .init(str: String(i))
  }
  
  @State private var bottomPageItems: [PageItem] = (0..<20).map { i in
      .init(str: String(i))
  }
  
  @State private var draggingItem: PageItem?
  let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(spacing: 10), count: 3)

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ScrollView(.vertical) {
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
          ForEach(self.topPageItems) { pageItem in
            PageView(page: pageItem)
              .id(pageItem.id)
              .draggable(pageItem) {
                PageView(page: pageItem)
                  .id(pageItem.id)
                  .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                  .onAppear {
                    self.draggingItem = pageItem
                  }
              }
              .dropDestination(for: PageItem.self) { items, location in
                self.draggingItem = nil
                return false
              } isTargeted: { status in
                guard let draggingItem, status, draggingItem.id != pageItem.id else { return }
                if let sourceIndex = self.topPageItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id ==  draggingItem.id }) {
                  let destinationIndex = self.topPageItems.firstIndex { $0.id == pageItem.id }
                  guard let destinationIndex else { return }
                  
                  withAnimation(.bouncy) {
                    let sourceItem = self.topPageItems.remove(at: sourceIndex)
                    self.topPageItems.insert(sourceItem, at: destinationIndex)
                  }
                } else if let sourceIndex = self.bottomPageItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id ==  draggingItem.id }) {
                  let destinationIndex = self.topPageItems.firstIndex { $0.id == pageItem.id }
                  guard let destinationIndex else { return }
                  
                  withAnimation(.bouncy) {
                    let sourceItem = self.bottomPageItems.remove(at: sourceIndex)
                    self.topPageItems.insert(sourceItem, at: destinationIndex)
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
        .padding(15)
      }
      
      ScrollView(.vertical) {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
          ForEach(self.bottomPageItems) { pageItem in
            PageView(page: pageItem)
              .id(pageItem.id)
              .draggable(pageItem) {
                PageView(page: pageItem)
                  .id(pageItem.id)
                  .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                  .onAppear {
                    self.draggingItem = pageItem
                  }
              }
              .dropDestination(for: PageItem.self) { items, location in
                self.draggingItem = nil
                return false
              } isTargeted: { status in
                guard let draggingItem, status, draggingItem.id != pageItem.id else { return }
                if let sourceIndex = self.bottomPageItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id ==  draggingItem.id }) {
                  let destinationIndex = self.bottomPageItems.firstIndex { $0.id == pageItem.id }
                  guard let destinationIndex else { return }
                  
                  withAnimation(.bouncy) {
                    let sourceItem = self.bottomPageItems.remove(at: sourceIndex)
                    self.bottomPageItems.insert(sourceItem, at: destinationIndex)
                  }
                } else if let sourceIndex = self.topPageItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id ==  draggingItem.id }) {
                  let destinationIndex = self.bottomPageItems.firstIndex { $0.id == pageItem.id }
                  guard let destinationIndex else { return }
                  
                  withAnimation(.bouncy) {
                    let sourceItem = self.topPageItems.remove(at: sourceIndex)
                    self.bottomPageItems.insert(sourceItem, at: destinationIndex)
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
        .padding(15)
      }
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}


import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct PageItem: Identifiable, Codable, Transferable {
  let id: UUID
  let str: String
  let color: Color
  
  init(str: String) {
    self.id = UUID()
    self.str = str
    let allColors: [Color] = [.green, .blue, .pink, .orange, .purple]
    self.color = allColors.randomElement()!
  }
  
  static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
    CodableRepresentation(for: PageItem.self, contentType: .content)
  }
}

struct PageView: View {
  let page: PageItem
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      page.color
      Text(page.str)
        .font(.title)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
  }
}

extension Color: Codable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case red
    case green
    case blue
    case opacity
  }
  
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0
    var opacity: CGFloat = 0
    
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    UIColor(self).getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &opacity)
    try container.encode(red, forKey: .red)
    try container.encode(green, forKey: .green)
    try container.encode(blue, forKey: .blue)
    try container.encode(opacity, forKey: .opacity)
  }
  
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let red = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .red)
    let green = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .green)
    let blue = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .blue)
    let opacity = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .opacity)
    self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: opacity)
  }
}
```